# Importing bootstrap sass: 24em*px isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, sass-loader

Bootstrap (4.3.1) is imported through NPM. Sass loader (Webpack) fails. This is the error message:

> 24em*px isn't a valid CSS value.

This error is found on (line 491, column 100) in node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss

This line: `$input-height-inner: calc(#{$input-line-height * 1em} + #{$input-padding-y * 2}) !default;`

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28240

Comment: @ReSedano Thanks a lot! That solved my problem.

Comment: Great! You're welcome! ;-)